# How to play RTSP stream under Linux for the BOSCH AutoDome Junior HD IVA camera?

Tags: linux, video, streaming

I have a AutoDome Junior HD IVA camera. How do I play RTSP stream in my Linux distro? I tried VLC but it fails. Is there any other reliable tool?

**Follow up**:

Try 1: fail

```
$ mplayer rtsp://192.168.1.10:554
MPlayer SVN-r33251-4.6.0 (C) 2000-2011 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing rtsp://192.168.1.10:554.
Connecting to server 192.168.1.10[192.168.1.10]: 554...

rtsp_session: unsupported RTSP server. Server type is 'unknown'.
STREAM_LIVE555, URL: rtsp://192.168.1.10:554
Stream not seekable!
 file format detected.
Initiated "video/H264" RTP subsession on port 43230
demux_rtp: Failed to guess the video frame rate
VIDEO:  [H264]  0x0  0bpp  0.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
FPS not specified in the header or invalid, use the -fps option.
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
V:   0.0   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0                                    


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Try 2: fail

```
$ mplayer mms://192.168.1.10:554
MPlayer SVN-r33251-4.6.0 (C) 2000-2011 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing mms://192.168.1.10:554.
STREAM_ASF, URL: mms://192.168.1.10:554
Connecting to server 192.168.1.10[192.168.1.10]: 554...

Connected
read error:: Resource temporarily unavailable
pre-header read failed
Connecting to server 192.168.1.10[192.168.1.10]: 554...

unknown ASF streaming type
Failed, exiting.
Connecting to server 192.168.1.10[192.168.1.10]: 554...

Cache size set to 320 KBytes
Cache fill:  0.00% (0 bytes)   nop_streaming_read error : Resource temporarily unavailable
Stream not seekable!
Cache fill:  0.00% (0 bytes)   nop_streaming_read error : Resource temporarily unavailable
Cache fill:  0.00% (0 bytes)   

Cache not filling, consider increasing -cache and/or -cache-min!
nop_streaming_read error : Resource temporarily unavailable
Cache not filling, consider increasing -cache and/or -cache-min!
nop_streaming_read error : Resource temporarily unavailable
Cache not filling, consider increasing -cache and/or -cache-min!
nop_streaming_read error : Resource temporarily unavailable
Cache not filling, consider increasing -cache and/or -cache-min!
nop_streaming_read error : Resource temporarily unavailable
Cache not filling, consider increasing -cache and/or -cache-min!
Invalid seek to negative position!


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mplayer, it's usually the audio and video player that supports the widest range of formats.

If you have a supposedly RTSP source which is actually an HTTP URL, first retrieve the contents of the URL; you'll get a file containing just another URL, this time `rtsp://` (sometimes you get another HTTP URL that you need to follow too). Pass the `rtsp://` URL to mplayer on its command line.

There are servers out there (and, for all I know, hardware devices too) that serve files containing a `rtsp://` URL over HTTP, but then serve content in the [MMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server) protocol¹. This is for compatibility with some older Microsoft players (my memory is hazy over the details), but it breaks clients that believe that RTSP is RTSP and MMS is MMS. If you obtain an `rtsp://` URL that doesn't work at all, try replacing the scheme with `mms://`.

¹  <sub>No relation with [Multimedia Messaging Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service) a.k.a. video SMS.</sub>

Comment: i tried but both fails. Please see above.

Answer (score 7):

I've found that the `ffmpeg` utilities are often more reliable. Try:

`$ ffplay 'rtsp://username:password@ip_address:port/url'`

Also note that IP camera RTSP streams **frequently require a username and password**.

The defaults for Foscam-compatible cameras: **port** is `88` and **url** is either `videoMain`, `videoSub`, or `audio`.

More details are available at the [ffmpeg manual](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp). Interestingly, ffmpeg instructions don't seem to include documentation about including **username** and **password** fields, which are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is indeed an RTSP stream, you should be able to open it with `vlc`  like this:

```
$ vlc rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/[Stream Name]
```

If a username/password is required, *vlc* accepts such in the URL.  For example:

```
rtps://username:password@192.168.1.10:554/[Stream Name]
```

It is also possible to specify the stream through the *vlc* GUI interface:

```
Media > Open Network Stream ...
```

In the Open Media panel, on the Network tab, enter the URL in the "Please enter a network URL" box.

The stream name should be mentioned somewhere in the user interface (UI) for the camera system.  For example, a Swann camera DVR UI mentions the stream name is formatted like (but this naturally may differ by manufacturer and model number):

```
ch01/0
```

Where **ch01** is the camera, and **0** identifies a stream the camera makes available.

Based on information for BOSCH (and many other brands) found [here](https://camera-sdk.com/p_6650-how-to-connect-to-a-bosch-camera.html), Bosch Autodome cameras may expect a stream name like:

```
video
```

-or-

```
rtsp_tunnel
```

Comment: This does not appear to be a full answer, nor does it include any explanation. You should expand upon your answer.

Comment: I was surprised that `vlc` plays some streams which `mplayer` isn't able to.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the latest version of the AutoDome Junior HD firmware. (At this time: 4.54.0024.)

I found information about RTSP in Bosch's IP cameras [here](http://www.svasecu.com/bosch/literature/en-US/VIPX1600XFModul_ConfigurationNote_BVIPAndRTSP_enUS_T4572265227.pdf) (pfd).

If you put a password in the camera, you must type the username and password in VLC.

I'm testing with the `VIP-X1XF E` encoder. Works great, with audio, in VLC (on Windows7).